# Generalization of "remove all duplicates"

Tags: c++, containers, element

Let `related` be a binary predicate.  Let us define a "relation subset" as the set of all elements such that any element in the subset is related to at least one other element in the subset via 'related', other than itself (hence whether an element is related to itself or not is irrelevant in forming the relation subsets).  Note:  a relation subset is NOT necessarily a [strongly connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component).  For example, suppose A is related to B, and B and C are related to each other.  Then {A,B,C} is a relation subset by definition, but is not a strongly connected component because there is no path from B to A or from C to A via 'related'.

Note that 'related' is not necessarily symmetric, i.e. related(a,b) == true does not necessarily mean that related(b,a) == true, nor is it transitive, i.e. related(a,b) == true and related(b,c) == true does not necessarily imply related(a,c) == true.  As far as I can see, no restrictions on the binary predicate `related` need be imposed in order to partition a set into relation subsets.  If an element x is not related to any element at all (other than itself), then {x} is itself its own relation subset.

One good problem is to define

```
template <typename Container, typename BinaryPredicate>
void partition (Container& container, BinaryPredicate related);
```

that will sort the elements of container so that the container is partitioned into its relation subsets.  This question arose quickly after attempting the original problem:

```
template <typename Container, typename BinaryPredicate>
void removeRelated (Container& container, BinaryPredicate related);
```

which is to remove (from `container`) all elements from each relation subset, except for the first one of each subset found in the container.

Of course, equality is just a special case of 'related', and hence this is a generalization of "remove all duplicates" (that is how I thought up this question, by trying to generalize that well-known solved problem).  What we want is to keep one representative of each relation subset, namely the first one according to the container's ordering of elements.

Below is the code I tried to implement, with the following relationships :

```
Bob knows Mary
Mary knows Jim
Jim knows Bob
Sally knows Fred
Fred knows no one.
```

In this example, A is related to B if and only if A knows B. {Bob, Mary, Jim} is a relation subset because each person is related to someone else (Bob is related to Mary, Mary is related to Jim, Jim is related to Bob). Note that {Sally, Fred} is NOT a relation subset because though Sally is related to Fred, Fred is not related to Sally. Thus we are left with {Sally}, {Fred} as the other two relation subsets.

So the final answer should be : Bob, Sally, Fred.  Note that if the function `partition` were to be defined, then it would simply leave {Bob, Mary, Jim, Sally, Fred} unchanged, with Bob, Sally, Fred being the first element of each partition.  Hence even if we had the `partition` function (not to be confused with std::partition of course, but I'm not really thinking about a good name right now), it is still not immediately clear what `removeRelated` would need.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <set>

template<typename Container, typename BinaryPredicate>
void removeRelated (Container& container, BinaryPredicate related) {
    using element = typename Container::value_type;
    std::set<element> s;
    for (typename Container::iterator it = std::begin(container);  it != std::end(container); ) {
        if (std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
                [=](const element& x)->bool {return related(*it,x);}) != s.end())
            it = container.erase(it);  // *it is related to an element in s.
        else {
            s.insert(*it);
            it++;
        }
    }
}

struct Person {  // Used for testing removeRelated.
    std::string name;
    std::list<Person*> peopleKnown;
    Person (const std::string& n) : name(n) {}
    void learnsAbout (Person* p) {peopleKnown.push_back(p);}
    bool knows (Person* p) const {
        return std::find(peopleKnown.begin(), peopleKnown.end(), p) != peopleKnown.end();
    }
};

int main() {
    Person *bob = new Person("Bob"), *mary = new Person("Mary"), *jim = new Person("Jim"),
        *sally = new Person("Sally"), *fred = new Person("Fred");
    bob->learnsAbout(mary);
    mary->learnsAbout(jim);
    jim->learnsAbout(bob);
    sally->learnsAbout(fred);
    std::list<Person*> everybody {bob, mary, jim, sally, fred};
    removeRelated (everybody, [](Person* a, Person* b)->bool {return a->knows(b);});
    for (const Person* x : everybody) std::cout << x->name << ' ';  // Bob Mary Sally Fred
//  Should be 'Bob Sally Fred' since {Bob, Mary, Jim}, {Sally}, {Fred} are the relation subsets.
}
```

The bug from the code above is that Mary is inserted into 's' because at that point she is not related to anyone in s (through 'knows'). In the end, she is related to Jim, who is related to Bob (and Bob to Mary) through 'knows', and hence {Bob, Mary, Jim} is a relation subset, so bob should be the only one of these three people in 's'.

But during the iteration the function does not know that. How can I fix the algorithm?
One idea is to perhaps first define the function `partition` mentioned above, i.e. to sort the container so that the container is partitioned into its relation subsets (which is a very nice problem in itself, and could very well be the main question at hand), and then simply take the first element of each partition.

Another idea is to replace the lambda function

```
[=](const element& x)->bool {return related(*it,x);}
```

with

```
[=](const element& x)->bool {return relatedIndirectly(*it,x);}
```

and I think it might solve the problem, where the helper function relatedIndirectly searches for a chain of relations to x.

Here is another example examined by Cimbali (below).  Suppose A is related to B, A is related to C, B is related to C.  Then {A,B} cannot be a relation subset because B is not related to A.
Similarly, {A,C} and {B,C} cannot be relation subsets (C is not related to A, and C is not related to B), and {A,B,C} definitely not since C is not related to anyone.
{A}, {B}, {C} is the only partitioning that satisfies my definition of relation subsets.

Conjecture: A relation subset is always the union of strongly connected components such that each strongly connected component in the union has at least one element that is related to some element in a different strongly connected component in the union.  But this would need mathematical proof.

**Update:**
I've strengthened the above definition of related subset (greatly) so that:
BinaryPredicate 'related' shall be reflexive (related(x,x) == true for any x), symmetric (related(x,y) implies related(y,x)), and transitive (related(x,y) and related(y,z) implies related(x,z)).  This partitions any set into equivalence classes.  removeRelated shall remove all elements from every equivalence class except for the first element in the container.  This generalizes the classic problem of "remove all duplicates", since equality is a special case of an equivalence relation.  The following code now gives the correct results, but I wonder if there is a way to weaken the condition of 'related' and still get the same results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <set>

template<typename Container, typename BinaryPredicate>
void removeRelated (Container& container, BinaryPredicate related) {
    using element = typename Container::value_type;
    std::set<element> s;
    for (typename Container::iterator it = std::begin(container);  it != std::end(container); ) {
        if (std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
                [=](const element& x)->bool {return related(*it,x);}) != s.end())
            it = container.erase(it);  // *it is related to an element in s.
        else {
            s.insert(*it);
            it++;
        }
    }
}

// Used for testing removeRelated.  Person::isRelativeOf is an equivalence relation.
struct Person {
    std::string name;
    std::list<Person*> relatives;
    Person (const std::string& n) : name(n) {relatives.push_back(this);}  // Forcing reflexivity
    void addRelative (Person* p) {
        for (Person* relatives_of_p : p->relatives)
            relatives.push_back(relatives_of_p);  // Forcing transitivity ('relatives.push_back(p);' included in this)
        p->relatives.push_back(this);  // Forcing symmetry
    }
    bool isRelativeOf (Person* p) const {
        return std::find(relatives.begin(), relatives.end(), p) != relatives.end();
    }
};

int main() {
    Person *bob = new Person("Bob"), *mary = new Person("Mary"), *jim = new Person("Jim"),
        *sally = new Person("Sally"), *fred = new Person("Fred");
    bob->addRelative(mary);  // crashes
    mary->addRelative(jim);
    jim->addRelative(bob);
    sally->addRelative(fred);
    std::list<Person*> everybody {bob, mary, jim, sally, fred};
    removeRelated (everybody, [](Person* a, Person* b)->bool {return a->isRelativeOf(b);});
    for (const Person* x : everybody) std::cout << x->name << ' ';  // Bob Sally (correct)
}
```

If 'related' is 'knows' or 'is friends of', which need not be symmetric nor transitive, will we still have a partitioning and thus removeRelated can still work?

And another question I wonder about is:  what is the fastest sorting algorithm to sort the above so that the equivalence classes consist of consecutive elements?  This is what I came up with:

```
template<typename Container, typename BinaryPredicate>
void sortByEquivalenceClasses (Container& container, BinaryPredicate related) {
    for (auto it = container.begin();  it != container.end();  ++it)
        for (auto jt = std::next(it);  jt != container.end();  ++jt)
            if (related(*it, *jt)) {
                std::iter_swap(jt, std::next(it));
                break;
            }
}
```

But the sort does not preserve the original relative ordering of the elements.  How to preserve that?

Comment: Look at [Strongly connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component)

Comment: Shouldn't {Sally,Fred} be a relation subset, instead of {Sally}, {Fred} ?

Comment: Yes, the problem is fuzzy on some definitions. I don't think "a unique relation subset" is correct, rather "at least one relation subset". I'm also not clear on what a relation is, since it isn't symmetric (to know or to be known ?)

Comment: The notion of "relation subset" is ill-defined. Suppose "related" = "married to". Is a set of all married people a relation subset? According to the definition, it is, because each person in the subset is related to some other person in the subset.

Comment: @at n.m.  If bigamy is not permitted.  Then all married couples will form their own UNIQUE relation subsets and all single people will be unique singleton subsets.  If polygamy is allowed, then suppose A is married to B and B is married to C and married to D, and C is married to E.  Then {A,B,C,D,E} is a unique relation subset.  I believe everything is well-defined.  Regarding your first question, the problem is to simply take the first representatives of each relation subset, but the real problem at hand foremost here is to first get the program to obtain these relation subsets.

Comment: Typing "unique" in all caps doesn't make it so, you need to prove it. Please look at the definition of relation subset and explaim how any bunch of married couples does not qualify. "Any element in the subset is related to at least one other" — check.

Comment: To put it in concrete terms, if A married to B and C married to D, then {A, B, C, D} is a relation subset. If you don't want it, you need to change your definition. If you want relation subset to be a *weakly connected component* just say so. It will then indeed be unique.

Comment: I don't think my definition of a relation subset meets the criteria of a weakly connected component either, after reading the definition of weakly connected component.

Comment: Your definition clearly doesn't correspond to your intention so you need to replace either of them. If you want weakly connected, change your definition accordingly. If you want something else, decide what it is. You cannot keep your definition and claim uniqueness because it simply does not define anything unique.

Comment: If you want a strongly connected component for a symmetric relation induced by your relation, that's OK too.

Comment: I think it is a weakly connected component with a the condition that if A is related to B only and B is not related to anything, then {A,B} is not a relation subset, but must instead be split into {A}, {B}.  My definition, fully stated in my question (I cannot elaborate more than that), then agrees with my definition.

Comment: I think you keep tweaking your definition with no clear goal in sight, which is why it will break down again and again as you discover more edge cases. Let's set things straight. If you divide your set into disjoint subsets, you induce a new *equivalence relation*. Try to describe that new relation in terms of your old "related" relation. Note it must be symmetric, reflexive and transitive.

Comment: Ok, in my update above, I've strengthened 'related' so that it is symmetric, reflexive and transitive, and everything works correctly now.  But now the problem is too easy.  Can 'related' be weakened somehow and 'removeRelated' still give the same results?  For example, supposed 'related' is 'friends of', so that symmetric and transitive need not hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you define a subset by the following

> Let us define a "relation subset" as the set of all elements such that any element in the subset is related to at least one other element in the subset via 'related', other than itself

This sound a bit recursive, but as I understand it

- A node `n` without outgoing relations is in the subset that is the singleton `{n}`
- A node `n` that has outgoing relations only to singletons, is in the subset that is the singleton `{n}`
- Any cycle (of any length), and more generally any strongly connected component forms a subset, **including all their predecessor nodes** for the relation.

Example. The following relations :

```
A -> B
B -> A
C -> B
D -> C
E -> F
```

Define the following subsets : `{A, B, C, D}`, `{E}` and `{F}`

---

Assuming the above is correct, we can devise the following algorithm (pseudocode) :

```
int visit(Node n, int s) { // returns 0 iff there is no cycle anywhere beneath

    if(length(n.relations) = 0 || n.singleton == true)
    // leaves, or only leaves below
    {
        n.singleton = true;
        return false;
    }
    else if(n.visited == true || n.bigger_subset > 0)
    // part of a subcycle, or predecessor of one
    {
        n.bigger_subset = s;
        return true;
    }
    else
    // searching for the nature of what is below
    {
        n.visited = true;
        bool found_cycle = 0;

        for each node m such that n is related to m (n -> m)
            found_cycle = max(Visit(m), found_cycle);

        if( found_cycle > 0 )
            n.bigger_subset = found_cycle;
        else
            n.singleton = true; // parent of only singletons

        n.visited = false;
        return found_cycle;
    }
}

s = length(node_set) + 1; // clearly bigger than the maximal number of subsets
for n in node_set:
{
    if( n.singleton == false && n.big_subcycle == 0 )
    {
        // state unknown, it is thus the first of its subset, unless it is a predecessor (or part) of a known subset
        int set = visit(n, s);

        // not a singleton, and not the current set : a previous one
        if( set > s )
            node_set.remove(n);

        s--;
    }
    else
        node_set.remove(n);
}
```

What this does is basically a depth-first search from each element on, marking nodes that are being visited, in order to detect cycles. By remembering the state of each node, any predecessor of a subset can be added to the subset without going down to the cycle again.

---

Here is the C code for this algorithm on the example given above : http://ideone.com/VNumcN

Comment: {A, B, C, D}, {E} and {F} is the correct partitioning into relation subsets.  I will analyze your pseudocode and try to implement it if it looks correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Any cycle (of any length), and more generally any strongly connected component forms a subset, including all their predecessor nodes for the relation.".  A strongly connected component will always be a SUBSET of a relation subset, but not necessarily a relation subset in its own right.  "all their predecessor nodes for the relation" are the remaining elements outside the strongly connected component but in the relation subset?  I will also need help from others to confirm that the pseudocode is correct before I try to implement it.

Comment: @prestokeys yes, that is what I mean

Comment: Cimbali. Thanks for your interest in this question, but n.m. has convinced me that perhaps my question is ill-formed.  I've already edited my question by strengthening the condition and answered it, but to weaken the condition as much as I did originally perhaps leads to no solution.  I also don't really understand your pseudocode (again, probably because my original question is ill-formed).

Comment: @prestokeys http://ideone.com/VNumcN --- the code, which works on your initial definition of relation and subsets. If you want to use a symmetric relation, you can use the same program by always putting `relations[x][y] = relations[y][x]`, though it will probably not be optimized for that.

Comment: Wow!  It works???  I was pretty convinced by n.m. (who seems to have a math background in set theory) that the initial conditions were not well-defined.  I will thoroughly study your code, and accept your answer.

Comment: `int visit(int v, int set, int n, int status[n], int visited[n], int relations[n][n])` is an illegal declaration according to GCC.4.8.1 (using parameter n outside of function body).  So I edited your code so that `visit` and `select_rep` use template parameter N instead.  Now it compiles.  I still haven't studied your code yet, though.